# OnEnable not updating variables - Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I have a pool of enemies that follow the player being activated/deactivated during the game.
The problem is once they are reactivated, they retain the rigidbody.velocity values they had before being deactivated and don't update them as I wrote on the OnEnable() function, so they just go somewhere else instead of following the player.
My code is as follows:

```
public class EnemyFollow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject playerPos;
    protected Rigidbody rb;
    bool secondSpawn = false;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        if (secondSpawn)
        {
            Vector3 dir = new Vector3(playerPos.transform.position.x - transform.position.x,
                playerPos.transform.position.y - transform.position.y,
                playerPos.transform.position.z - transform.position.z).normalized;
            rb.velocity = dir;
        }
    }   
    void Start()
    {
        playerPos = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        Vector3 dir = (playerPos.transform.position - transform.position).normalized;
        rb.velocity = dir;
        secondSpawn = true;
    }
```

I'm sure I'm making a noob mistake, but I just can't figure it out.
Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Try a Debug.log in the first line of the function to see if it's called.

Comment: I did. And it did call the Debug.log.
Still, they are moving in the wrong direction when they are reactivated :\

Comment: Show your code for deactivating and reactivating your enemies.

Comment: That is kind of redundant. I just have a basic pooling system.
I'm not setting them any properties when deactivating. And upon activation I just set them a random point on the map.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `OnEnable`, but no `OnDisable`, try to set your rigidbody properties reset inside OnDisable.

Also remember that `OnEnable` will be executed before `Start`.

More about execution order [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html).

Comment: It's because OnEnable runs before start that I thought of using it. And Start only runs once, so after the first Start it would run the OnEnable code.
I'll try to reset on disable and get right back at you!

Comment: Just tried to get the RigidBody component and set its velocity to new Vector3(0,0,0).
They still behave the same way. Some enemies will follow the player on activation, yet some wont and will just roam in the direction of infinity.